# How do I destroy an Exchange Database Availability Group and the associated cluster?

Tags: exchange-2010

There's a lot of documentation out there on how to create an Exchange 2010 DAG, but not much on how to revert back to a single server. Has anyone ever done this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had to follow this process but I suspect the actions would be as follows:

3. Remove the servers from the DAG (instructions on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351278.aspx))
4. Remove the DAG ([Technet info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335069.aspx))

As I say I've never done this before but hopefully this info will give you a place to start and someone can weigh in with a more detailed step-by-step or information.

Comment: These steps worked. It ended up being simpler than I thought and without any serious gotchas. Also, removing the DAG destroys the failover cluster, which was my biggest concern.